# DC-DC converter/regulator lead-acid battery charger design question

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am trying to build a DC-DC voltage converter/regulator for a bicycle generator (dynamo). Expected unregulated input voltage range will vary with the speed of the bicycle (about 0 - 120Vdc) and want a constant output of about 15Vdc and output current of 3A

Can I use buck-boost converter? or something else? Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: It's not clear whether you are planning to charge the battery at 15V, but that's a pretty high charging voltage. Make sure that your battery can tolerate that voltage...most lead acid batteries are charged at about 2.3V to 2.4V per cell.

Answer (score 2):

I'd start off with a buck regulator that is capable, when the input voltage is insufficient, of just acting as a milli ohm short. This gets you 15v for all voltages greater than about 16 volts going in.

For slow speeds read on....

That's a decent beginning. Then you have to ask yourself how you are going to get 45 watts from an inefficient bicycle dynamo at slow speeds.

After a while, you might decide that theoretically you'll never be able to pedal hard enough from a standing start and hopefully soon realize that your spec is unrealistic and impossible to achieve.